# Guarantee minimum interval from setInterval

Tags: javascript

As you can see in the output, the difference is sometimes <1000, but my expectation is >=1000 always. Is there a way to guarantee this?

```js
var t = Date.now()

setInterval(function () {
  console.log(`Difference`, Date.now() - t)
  t = Date.now()
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Can you add some context as to why it is important that it can't be faster than the interval? That might be relevant on the way to guarantee it.

Comment: I want to ping my backend every **m** minutes. If there are multiple tabs, I don't want all the tabs to ping. To achieve this, I'm planning to leverage the fact that there will be slight differences in the time the `setInterval` callback executes in each tab - the one that gets executed first will put an entry of `Date.now()` in **localStorage**. Others will check if the difference between `Date.now()` and the entry in **localStorage** is >=m before pinging.

Would be great if you can suggest a better way to achieve this 

Comment: I see. It depends a bit on the goal of the ping. If it is just a simple ping with little data and no heavy performance hit on the server, then I wouldn't even bother. Sending a small package to the server 20 times per minute wont cause much damage. If the goal is to get an update from the server, then [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) might be a solution so that the server sends the data to the browser when necessary, instead of the browser having to ask the server all the time. Otherwise Suthan's answer might be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the interval is really firing after every 1000ms, but the fact that the next timer starts before resetting the `t = Date.now()` is skewing the difference. If you're really concerned about the value of difference, then you can change the code to the following:

```
var t = Date.now()
const timerFn = function () {
  console.log(`Difference`, Date.now() - t)
  t = Date.now()
  setTimeout(timerFn, 1000)
};
setTimeout(timerFn, 1000)
```

**Sequence of events**

- `t = Date.now()`
- Starts a timer for 1000ms
- Timer reached 1000ms. Prior to executing the callback function, we now start a new timer for the next execution.
- Execute the callback function. Console logs the `"Difference", Date.now() - t`.
- Re-initializes `t = Date.now()`. (Keep in mind, this re-initialization doesn't happen at the same exact moment as the new timer started. There has been some delays (in ms of course)). This is why you saw the discrepancy.

Comment: "next timer starts before resetting the t = Date.now()" - I don't get this

Comment: As you can see from 
```
setInterval(function () {
  console.log(`Difference`, Date.now() - t)
  t = Date.now()
}, 1000)
```
Since it's a `setInterval`, after the first `1000ms`, the order of events goes like this: 1: it initiates a new timer to run the callback again
2: it runs the callback function. At that point, we have lost a couple of milliseconds. So that means, by the time we re-initialize the `t=Date.now()` we have lost a couple of milliseconds. So, the next time we do `Date.now() - t`, we'll see the milliseconds lost reflected there. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Schedule next execution → execute current callback. Yes, makes sense if we think this is how `setInterval` works.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can refer to this[Why use setTimeout to simulate setInterval](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000038829248)

```js
let startTime = new Date().getTime();
let count = 0;
// time consuming task
setInterval(function() {
  let i = 0;
  while (i++ < 1000000000);
}, 0);
setInterval(function() {
  count++;
  console.log(
    "The time difference from the original set interval is:",
    new Date().getTime() - (startTime + count * 1000),
    "millisecond"
  );
}, 1000);
// output:
// Time difference from the original set interval: 699 milliseconds
// Time difference from the original set interval: 771 ms
// Time difference from the original set interval: 887 milliseconds
// The time difference from the original set interval: 981 milliseconds
// Time difference from the original set interval: 1142 milliseconds
// Time difference from the original set interval: 1822 milliseconds
// Time difference from the original set interval: 1891 milliseconds
// The time difference from the original set interval: 2001 milliseconds
// The time difference from the original set interval: 2748 milliseconds
// ...
```

This author in the link proposes the following workaround for this,use setTimeout to simulate setInterval

1. Write an interval method

```js
let timer = null
interval(func, wait){
    let interv = function(){
        func.call(null);
        timer=setTimeout(interv, wait);
    };
    timer= setTimeout(interv, wait);
 },
```

```js
//2. Use it like setInterval()
interval(function() {}, 20);

//3. Terminate the timer
if (timer) {
  window.clearSetTimeout(timer);
  timer = null;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/361628